# How indexing work for dictionary in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have an elastic index containing a dictionary in each document.

```
Docs: 
{
    "name" : "name1", 
    "paymentDict":
     { 
           "card1": { "CardType": "Credit", "CardName": "Axis"}, 
           "card2": { "CardType": "Debit", "CardName": "Axis"}
     }
}
```

Dictionary Type: `Dictionary<int,object>`

I am expecting a good amount of write on this elastic index and want to test the performance aspect and didn't find anything useful in elastic docs explaining explicitly about the dictionary indexing. Need help in below query

1. How does indexing work for the dictionary?
2. Is this indexing will be the same as `List<object>`?

Answer (score 3):

that would be an object in Elasticsearch - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/object.html

you could also make this super simple and just have a document per card, that way you flatten things out